# query data according into specific timezone in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, moment-timezone

As you know, by default mongoDB saves records with timestamps (`createdAt`, `updatedAt`) into utc timezone.

**Issue:**
At our system, one user is registered on 21st December at 2 AM. But as per UTC timezone, mongoDB stored that record with `createdAt` as 20st december, 8:30 PM in users collection. So, when I am trying querying users which are registered on 21st December, MongoDB not returning me that user according to below query.

**Query:**
How can I find records according to specific timezone or how can I modify my aggregate query to return me that user also?

**Current Code:**

```
let currentWeekDates = [
   '2022-12-19T00:00:00+08:00',
   '2022-12-20T00:00:00+08:00',
   '2022-12-21T00:00:00+08:00',
   '2022-12-22T00:00:00+08:00',
   '2022-12-23T00:00:00+08:00',
   '2022-12-24T00:00:00+08:00',
   '2022-12-25T00:00:00+08:00'
]

for (let date of currentWeekDates) {
    const formatedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    facet[formatedDate] = [
      {
        $match: {
          createdAt: { $gte: moment(date).startOf('day').toDate(), $lte: new Date(moment(date).endOf('day').toDate()) }
        }
      }
    ]
}

let data = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: facet
  }]
);
```

**Record from database:**

```
{
   first_name: 'test',
   email: 'test@gmail.com',
   createdAt: 2022-12-20T20:40:09.275+00:00
   updatedAt: 2022-12-20T20:40:09.275+00:0
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `new Date(moment(date).endOf('day').toDate())`? Just do `moment(date).endOf('day').toDate()`

Comment: Do you store the date values as string? You should **never** do that, it's a design flaw. From input data it is not clear.

Comment: I asked several times for more details, but you did not answer any of them. When you say "one user is registered on 21st December at 2 AM", then you should also provide the document according to this user instead of a random sample. And again, what is the desired output. Array `2022-12-19T00:00:00+08:00` to `2022-12-25T00:00:00+08:00` certainly returns document of `{ createdAt: ISODate('2022-12-21T08:00:00Z') }`. If the desired document is not returned, then you have a general problem with your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be an easier solution:

```
let currentWeekDates = [
   ISODate('2022-12-19T00:00:00+08:00'),
   ISODate('2022-12-20T00:00:00+08:00'),
   ISODate('2022-12-21T00:00:00+08:00'),
   ISODate('2022-12-22T00:00:00+08:00'),
   ISODate('2022-12-23T00:00:00+08:00'),
   ISODate('2022-12-24T00:00:00+08:00'),
   ISODate('2022-12-25T00:00:00+08:00')
]

let data = await User.aggregate([
{
  $bucket: {
      groupBy: "$createdAt",
      boundaries: currentWeekDates ,
      output: {
         data: { $push: { "$$ROOT" } }
      }
   }
}]);
```

Comment: Did you got my question? It was related to timezone wise search

Comment: Indeed, it is not clear at all, what you try to achieve. You did not provide an expected result, so it is a bit difficult to give right answer. Your query does not have any `$match` condition, so what does it mean when you say "not returning me that user according to below query"? Input dates are local times. All date related operations are internally done at UTC time, this is nothing you can change.

Comment: I have written every single detail I could.

Comment: @Kelly I do not agree. Once again: do you store the Date values as string? (What you should not do) An important missing detail would be: what is the expected result? And again, your question does not show any condition, statement "not returned me that user" does not make any sense.

Comment: As I already confirmed, I have shared everything I had. If you are not getting the question, please leave it.

Comment: Sorry, then I cannot help you. And looks like nobody else can help you either.

Comment: If you didn't got requirements even after that much details, it doesn't mean another person also won't get it.